# UIImageView alloc] initWithImage using IBOutlet not working

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I've typically followed the pattern of creating an object in my method (like `viewDidLoad`), have the property hold onto it, then release the original object created.  So something like this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
self.array = myArray;
[myArray release];
```

I thought I could do the same thing with `UIImageView`.  I have a `UIImageView` created in my `.xib`. I have an outlet to it that is a property like so

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

In my `viewDidLoad`, I do:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage;[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
self.imageView = imgView;
[imgView release];
```

If I run this, I do not get anything on screen.  However, if I do just this in my `viewDidLoad` instead:

```
[self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
```

I do get my arrow image on screen.  Is there something different about `UIImageView` that I am missing here?

Edit because of first response:  Is `UIImageView` different than `UITableView` in that I need to add it as a subview to my current view?  When I create a `UITableView` in `IB`, I do not add it as a `subview` in `viewDidLoad`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the point behind how `IBOutlet` work. If something is specified in `.xib` then it is already allocated for you :) You just use it.

Hence `[self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];` works since you just assigned an image to it.

However, when doing

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
self.imageView = imgView;
[imgView release];
```

you actually deallocated the `imageView` instance created by `IB` at the `self.imageView = imgView;` line and set a new one and neither did you added it as subview to anything. Since it is a new instance it will need to be added !! But anyways this approach is wrong if you are using `IBOutlet`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `self.imageView` to your view hierarchy.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageView = ...

    // You are missing this part!
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];

    ...
}
```

PS. You dont need to mark your `UIImageView` property as `IBOutlet` since you are not using `Interface Builder` to build your view.

Comment: Isn't it already added as it is created in the .xib file?  Like when I have a UITableView, I don't add it as a subview in viewDidLoad right?

Comment: The one you create in the xib file got overriden when you said self.imageView = imgView in viewDidLoad. If you are using IB dont recreate it in viewDidLoad